# Is that possible to add a column of data from one excel file to another without losing all the annotations on my first file?

Tags: r, excel, merge

I have two excels file (file1 and file2) :

- file1 is my working file, a list of gene IDs and many others columns with different information
- file2 is a file with also a list of gene IDs (some in common with file1) and others columns with different information.

I would like to add in file1 one of the column of file2, with the values correctly assigned to the IDs in common between file1 and file2. So I would like to keep all the annotations already present in file1 (color on the text, highlights etc...)

Do you have any idea how I could do that ?
Thanks in advance

I tried the merge function as follow :

```
merged_data <- left_join(data_file1, data_file2, by = c(id_col_file1 = id_col_file2))
```

The problem is that it creates a new datasheet with all the information I want, but losing all the annotations of my file1.

Comment: Look at this pkg `tidyxl`: https://nacnudus.github.io/tidyxl/index.html